# sorting when keys are not present javascript using localecompare

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6

I have json like below

```
[
{name:'aa',age:'1Y',address:'Alaska'},
{name:'cc',age:'4Years',address:'California'},
{name:'mm',address:'Texas'}
]
```

Whenever I sort with name and address it work but it will throw runtime error if I try to sort with age as it is missing on last entry.

This is my attempt

```js
let obj=[
{name:'aa',age:'2y',address:'Alaska'},
{name:'cc',age:'4y',address:'California'},
{name:'bb',address:'Texas'}
]
let field='age'; //work for name and address;
let mode='string';
if(mode!='number'){
console.log (obj.sort((a, b) => a[field].toString().localeCompare(b[field].toString())));
}
else{
console.log(obj.sort((a, b) => a[field] -b[field]))
}
```

What is the best way to ignore the entry when keys are not present , do I need to have seperate loop to check keys before sorting . Entry with missing keys will be on the bottom.

Ps: Ages are never >10 years from the business logic and they can come in any format like 1,1Y so it is treated as string

Comment: How should items with no age compare against items with an age? Should they be less than? Greater than? Whatever you want to happen, encode it in your sort callback.

Comment: edited the question

Comment: @sumit The answer you have changed to will sort ages in a wrong way (nl, 3 will be after 25, while 24 will be before 25), while my answer did sort them correct. Was there another reason to change the accepted answer?

Comment: The accepted answer has entries with missing key on the bottom, in my business logic age is always less than <10 years as it is the app kids under 10 years so that age sorting is okay. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Entry with missing keys will be on the bottom

Ask for the current value to decide what will be compared or what will be at the bottom.

```js
let obj=[{name:'aa',age:'2y',address:'Alaska'},{name:'cc',age:'4y',address:'California'},{name:'bb',address:'Texas'}],
    field = 'age';
    
console.log(obj.sort((a, b) => a[field] ? b[field] ? a[field].toString().localeCompare(b[field].toString()) : -1 : 1));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you want to compare the numbers within this string `10years` or this string `5y`, and so on, use a regex to compare the numbers.

```js
let obj=[{name:'aa',age:'24y',address:'Alaska'},{name:'cc',age:'4years',address:'California'},{name:'bb',address:'Texas'}],
    field = 'age';
    
console.log(obj.sort((a, b) => {
  let evaluate = () => {
    let aval = a[field].replace(/[^\d]/g, '').trim();
    let bval = b[field].replace(/[^\d]/g, '').trim();
    
    return aval !== '' && bval !== ''  ? Number(aval) - Number(bval) : a[field].toString().localeCompare(b[field].toString());
  };
  
  return a[field] ? b[field] ? evaluate() : -1 : 1
}));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This answer doesn't sort numerical fields correctly, 3 will be after 25 while 24 will be before 25...

Comment: The accepted answer has entries with missing key on the bottom, in my business logic age is always less than <10 years as it is the app kids under 10 years so that age sorting is okay. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Just make sure you either have the value of the object, or return an empty string.

The shortest code path would be

```
(a[field] || "")
```

Where you indicate that if `a` doesn't have the property, it will treat it as an empty string.

It won't cover for `a` being `null` though, so if that can happen, you have to check it more carefully still

```js
let obj = [{
    name: 'aa',
    age: '25',
    address: 'Alaska'
  },
  {
    name: 'cc',
    age: '25',
    address: 'California'
  },
  {
    name: 'bb',
    address: 'Texas'
  }
]
let field = 'age'; //work for name and address
console.log(obj.sort((a, b) => (a[field] || "").toString().localeCompare((b[field] || "").toString())));
```

Another way to do this, would be to simply compare the values (note, again, if `a` or `b` would be null, there might be a problem)

```js
let obj = [{
    name: 'aa',
    age: 25,
    address: 'Alaska'
  },
  {
    name: 'cc',
    age: 3,
    address: 'California'
  },
  {
    name: 'bb',
    address: 'Texas'
  }
]

function sortAndPrint( obj, field ) {
  console.log(`Sorting by ${field}`);
  console.log(obj.sort((a, b) => a[field] > b[field] ) );
}

sortAndPrint(obj, 'name');
sortAndPrint(obj, 'address');
sortAndPrint(obj, 'age');
```

Comment: That will get around the errors being thrown, but it's a bad way to compare ages. 3 would be considered greater than 20.

Comment: @kshetline true, made a small oversight on the update though. Currently he is sending the properties as a string, so I don't see why I would do the conversion based on the "real" type

Comment: **This is not ok according to OP**: *Entry with missing keys will be on the bottom*

Comment: @Ele Yeah, you are right, I have updated the answer with a different way ;-) Though in my defense, that wasn't there yet when the question was first asked :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let obj=[
  {name:'aa',age:'25',address:'Alaska'},
  {name:'cc',age:'25',address:'California'},
  {name:'bb',address:'Texas'}
]
let field='age'; //work for name and address
const sortFunc = (a, b) => a[field].toString().localeCompare(b[field].toString())

// If you can discard entries without the field
console.log(obj.filter(e => field in e).sort(sortFunc))

// If you cannot
console.log(obj.filter(e => field in e).sort(sortFunc).concat(obj.filter(e => !(field in e))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because on the last element you don't have the property age when you're trying to access it with property toString.(it is null with the age key)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you're looking for an overkill solution :)

```
  let obj=[
    {name: 'aa', age: 25, address: 'Alaska'},
    {name: 'cc', age: 24, address: 'California'},
    {name: 'mm', address: 'Texas'}
  ];

  let field = 'age';
  console.log (obj.sort((a, b) => {
    a = a[field];
    b = b[field];
    let defaultValue = '';

    if (typeof a === 'number' || typeof b === 'number') {
      defaultValue = 0;
    }

    a = a || defaultValue;
    b = b || defaultValue;

    if (typeof a === 'number') {
      return a - b;
    }
    else {
      return a.localeCompare(b);
    }
  }));
```

This automatically handles either strings or numbers, sorting correctly for each. If you want the no-age entries to sort higher rather than lower than everything else, just change what `defaultValue` is set to for numbers to a large number.